# Soap on jboss 7 is being a nightmare

Tags: java, soap, jboss7.x, seam2

i am running a soap service on jboss 7. i have a soap service bean which starts like this:

```
@Stateless 
@WebService(name = "AboxConfigurationMgt", targetNamespace = "http://com.atriumnetwork.ws/abox/configuration", serviceName = "AboxConfigurationMgtService")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL) 
public class AboxConfigurationServiceBean implements AboxConfigurationServiceLocal {
```

also another class starts like this:

```
@WebService(name = "AboxConfigurationMgt", targetNamespace = "http://com.atriumnetwork.ws/abox/configuration")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface AboxConfigurationMgt {
```

my standalone.xml is like this for the ws config:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
        <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
    </subsystem>
```

but when i run, i get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION_CAUGHT_WHILE_(PREPARING_FOR)_PERFORMING_THE_INVOCATION: org.jboss.ws.WSException: Target endpoint address not set
at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:359) [jbossws-native-core-4.0.2.GA.jar:4.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:246) [jbossws-native-core-4.0.2.GA.jar:4.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:176) [jbossws-native-core-4.0.2.GA.jar:4.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:162) [jbossws-native-core-4.0.2.GA.jar:4.0.2.GA]
at $Proxy158.generateNewConfig(Unknown Source)  at com.atriumnetwork.webportal.abconfig.logic.impl.GeneratConfigAction.valid(GeneratConfigAction.java:176) [myatrium_intranet.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
```

What am i doing wrong??? i would really appreciate any help. kind of desperate at the moment.

thanks in advance

Comment: You do something wrong in GeneratConfigAction.java:176, as i can see.

Comment: no its complaining about the end point. generateconfigaction just has the method. it works on jboss 5.1. there must be something wrong in the configuration as jboss 7 uses jbossws-cfx

Answer (score 0):

Try and add ejb.jar to your wWEB-INF\lib . To create endpoint you need to add the ejb jar to the lib. This is a common issue in as7.

Check out 
[here](https://community.jboss.org/message/761837?tstart=0)